# Receiving a SQL stored procedure error about changing schema but no changes have been mad

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2016

We have several data feeds that run every evening using SSIS packages with SQL table data sources. Part of this standard process is a data engine we've built using stored procedures that run for each data feed and returns that customers data based on their specific parameters. That engine dumps the data into a SQL table where it is retrieved by the package and then remains there until the next evenings run.

Maybe two weeks ago we started to intermittently get the following error running these stored procedures (which are executed using SQL Agent):

```
    "INSERT EXEC failed because the stored procedure altered the schema of the target table. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 556).  The step failed."
```

These stored procedures have been running for months, some even years, without being changed.  These errors just started intermittently occurring. Inside the stored procedure we do have a temporary table being used that receives the engine data and a table that is dropped and re-created using a statement like this:

```
    SELECT field1, field2 INTO sqlTable FROM @tempTable
```

I looked for a SQL updated or something that may have changed to cause these errors all of a sudden but can't find anything. It's occurred to several different stored procedures, intermittently, that all have this same kind of structure but I can't identify any particular reason.  It will happen one night and not another, to one stored procedure and not another just like it.  Any idea what could cause this?

We are running Microsoft SQL Server 2016  Standard 64-bit (13.0.4604.0) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor). This is all on a VM in the Azure environment.

Comment: Could the same procedure be running parallel? Or two different procedures, running at the same time, doing the same logic of `SELECT INTO` I'm guessing we'll need to see more of the procedure as the snipped above won't reproduce the error. The other question before the caffeine kicks in is about the error "INSERT EXEC" failed - does the procedure return a resultset that you're then smashing into another table?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `SELECT field1, field2 INTO sqlTable FROM @tempTable`? This will create a real table, not a temp table.

Comment: billinkc - I thought the same thing, is it running concurrently?  But there is 1 single process that calls it and it's scheduled once a day.  I checked history and there is only the one run.  As far as re-creating, it's been very intermittent.  It works fine right now and I have over a hundred of these running each night and a few different ones are failing every few nights.  No apparent rhyme or reason yet.  The final results are left in an actual table.

Comment: digital-aaron - The intention is to create a real table.  We will run the datasource job and then run a couple of packages off the same data.  Then we also like having last night's feed persist in case we have a question or issue about what is in there, we also have some reporting running off of "Last Night's Feed".  The engine and processing happens and the last two lines are generally a DROP of the final table and then a SELECT [fields] INTO that final table.  This is intentional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using "INSERT ... EXEC" and has enabled Query Store, it might be the reason.

The Query Data Store periodically runs auto-cleanup.

This has turned out to cause problems when a stored procedure makes a call to another stored procedure by using "INSERT…EXEC" syntax.

This is only an issue with SQL Server 2016

For more details and possible solution, see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4465511/error-556-insert-exec-failed-stored-procedure-altered-table-schema